# Training and validation samples are not what I have

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm having a weird issue. I'm trying to train a convolutional neural network (CNN) using `376` images. I have set around 80% of the images for training and around 20% for validation, as follows:

```
train = train_data[:300]
test = train_data[300:]
```

When I run the program however, I get the following:

```
Training samples: 900
Validation samples: 228
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
IndexError: index 525 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 300
```

I confirmed that I have the correct number of images, and not sure why I'm having this extra number of images in training and validation.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is `train_data`, are you sure that your indexing properly and not on some weird axis that is causing `numpy` to automagically reshape your arrays?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I'm reading color images (3-channels), while my inout shape was as follows:

```
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')
```

So, I simply had to replace `1` by `3`.